# Android GCM basic implementation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**UPDATE:** I fixed the problems in the code below so this makes a nice basic working example of how to use `GCM`

---

So, I'm trying to implement Android `GCM` into my app. Here are the relevant parts I've added to the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

...

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.badbob.app.gmctestapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I've added the following code to the onCreate of my main activity:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice( this );
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest( this );
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId( this );
    if( regId.equals( "" ) ) {
        GCMRegistrar.register( this, GCM_SENDER_ID );
    }
    else {
        Log.v( LOG_TAG, "Already registered" );
    }
```

I've also created the `GCMIntenetService` class like so:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "GetAClue::GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super( GCM_SENDER_ID );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService constructor called" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError( Context arg0, String errorId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onError called: " + errorId );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage( Context arg0, Intent intent ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onMessage called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Message is: " + intent.getStringExtra( "message" ) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onRegistered called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onUnregistered called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this in **LogCat**:

```
07-11 11:28:46.340: V/GCMRegistrar(27435): Registering receiver
07-11 11:28:46.370: D/GCMRegistrar(27435): resetting backoff for com.badbob.app.getacluebeta
07-11 11:28:46.380: V/GCMRegistrar(27435): Registering app com.badbob.app.getacluebeta of senders 128205395388
```

From what I've gleaned from other posts I should get a registration ID in `LogCat` but I"m not. Also `onRegistered()` in `GCMIntentService` never gets called. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just sign up for GCM? Try again a few hours later. Google APIs have a delay, your sender ID does not become active immediately.

Comment: I signed up more than 24 hours ago.

Comment: Can you show the code of your GCMBroadcastReceiver and GCMRegistrar classes?

Comment: Uhh, I haven't written those classes. What I posted is all the code I've written. I'm in missing something?

Comment: @yugidroid: those are library classes. Unlike C2DM, GCM comes with a helper library.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, thank you. Indeed. But why does Rooster242 have registered the receiver named "com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"? He must to registe the desired broadcast class extending a BrodcastReceiver that will trigger the ".GCMIntentService" service.

Comment: It's my understanding that the GCM library handles that for you which is why the class must be named exactly GCMIntentService. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Rooster242: Where is `GCM_SENDER_ID` defined/assigned?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this is incorrect

```
protected GCMIntentService( String senderId ) {         
super(senderId);}
```

As it states in the documentation. you must declare a PUBLIC, NO ARGUMENT constructor for GCMIntentService. Otherwise the GCMIntentService can't be instantiated properly by background intent services.

```
public GCMIntentService(){
super(senderID);}
```

the senderID can be a hard coded constant string because it will no longer change with the new GCM.
It's also very important you use the correct senderID. 24 hours is long enough for yours to be active so if my above solution doesn't work you are using the incorrect senderID. Everything else looks great.

The senderID is in the URL of your web browser when you are browsing the Google API access page. Click on GCM and a 12 digit number will be present in the browser URL. That is the correct key to use. NOT your API key. That is used on the App server side.

Comment: I had high hopes for this answer because it makes a lot of sense but alas, same issues... not getting a registration id and onRegistered not getting called. I changed the constructor to public, tried both with a parameter and without using hard coded constant sender ID. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct sender ID which you can see in the LogCat above (comes from https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:128205395388:access). I just noticed the Project ID field on the Google API Dashboard with a "register..." link next to it. Is that something I need?

Comment: No. you shouldn't need the Project ID. Sorry, missed something
    you should try adding a catagory tag in your manifest with the package name of your app
    
    <catagory android:name="yourAppPackageHere"

Comment: I also tried making all the other functions of GCMIntentService public but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: From the docs: "the category tag is not required for applications targeted to minSdkVersion 16 and higher."

Comment: The documentation lies! As soon as I added the <category> tag (in the correct place this time) it started working. Thanks Ryan, you spotted both problems with my code.

Comment: No problem, glad that it works. Kind of strange that the documentation is incorrect for that. Maybe you aren't actually running API 16 somehow.

Comment: The docs state if 'min_sdk' is 16 than one can omit it. But the OP is using 'min_sdk'=8

Answer (score 8):

I also had this ANNOYing bug, til now. The Problem was, that i declared the intentservice inside another package... even if i declared the name in the android manifest and no classnotfound exception had been place... no error at all could be found... so i made sure the intentservice is in the root package.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had run into the same problem where the GCMIntentService class was in another package and it would not respond to the registration intents. You're right, very annoying bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some issues in the code.

You should do the registration of your own broadcast receiver in the manifest file and that receiver will trigger the `<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />`.

Therefore you must do something like I write below.

- The receiver must be declared like:

  ```
  <receiver
      android:name="your.package.name.YourBroadCastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      </intent-filter>
  ```
- Your broadcast receiver that will start the service.

  ```
  public class YourBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
   public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       GCMIntentService .runIntentInService(context, intent);
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
   }  
  }
  ```

I advice you to take a look at the official GCM [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) where you can find a good example.

And... don't forget to enable the **Google Cloud Messaging** service in the main Google APIs Console page.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I see your point but I'm pretty sure the GCM library handles that for you. Exerpt (I've been all over the official documentation for the last two days btw): "This intent service will be called by the GCMBroadcastReceiver (which is is provided by GCM library), as shown in the next step. It must be named my_app_package.GCMIntentService, unless you use a subclass of GCMBroadcastReceiver that overrides the method used to name the service." So I tried your suggestion anyway by runIntentInService is a private method (and take 3 parameters, not 2).

Comment: For sanity sake I double checked and GCM is indeed enabled in google apis.

Answer (score 3):

See below tutorial for **GCM**:-

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

*Here I have written few steps for How to Get RegID and Notification starting from scratch*

1. Create/Register App on Google Cloud
2. Setup Cloud SDK with Development
3. Configure project for GCM
4. Get Device Registration ID
5. Send Push Notifications
6. Receive Push Notifications

You can find complete tutorial in below URL link

> [**Getting Started with Android Push Notification : Latest Google Cloud
> Messaging (GCM) - step by step complete tutorial**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-google-cloud.html)

[image]

Code snip to get Registration ID (Device Token for Push Notification).

**Configure project for GCM**

---

## Update AndroidManifest file

For enable GCM in our project we need to add few permission in our manifest file
Go to AndroidManifest.xml and add below code
Add Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET”/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name=“.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name=“<your_package_name_here>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name=“<your_package_name_here>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Add GCM Broadcast Receiver declaration

add GCM Broadcast Receiver declaration in your application tag

```
<application
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" ]]>
            <intent-filter]]>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="" />
            </intent-filter]]>

        </receiver]]>
     
<application/>
```

Add GCM Servie declaration

```
<application
     <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
<application/>
```

---

## Get Registration ID (Device Token for Push Notification)

**Now Go to your Launch/Splash Activity**

Add Constants and Class Variables

```
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private final static String TAG = "LaunchActivity";
protected String SENDER_ID = "Your_sender_id";
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm =null;
private String regid = null;
private Context context= null;
```

Update OnCreate and OnResume methods

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
     context = getApplicationContext();
         if (checkPlayServices()) 
     {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty())
            {
                registerInBackground();
            }
            else
            {
            Log.d(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }
      }
 }

@Override protected void onResume()
{
       super.onResume();       checkPlayServices();
}


# Implement GCM Required methods (Add below methods in LaunchActivity)

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported - Google Play Services.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
 }

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) 
{
   final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
   String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
   if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Registration ID not found.");
       return "";
   }
   int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
   int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
   if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.d(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) 
{
    return getSharedPreferences(LaunchActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private static int getAppVersion(Context context) 
{
     try 
     {
         PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
      } 
      catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
      {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
      }
}


private void registerInBackground() 
{     new AsyncTask() {
     Override
     protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
     {
          String msg = "";
          try 
          {
               if (gcm == null) 
               {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
               }
               regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);               Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
               Log.d(TAG, "Current Device's Registration ID is: "+msg);     
          } 
          catch (IOException ex) 
          {
              msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
          }
          return null;
     }     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
     { //to do here };
  }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

---

**Note** : please store REGISTRATION_KEY, it is important for sending PN Message to GCM
also keep in mine this will be unique for all device, by using this only GCM will send Push Notification.

## Receive Push Notifications

Add GCM Broadcast Receiver Class

As we have already declared “GcmBroadcastReceiver.java” in our Manifest file, So lets create this class
update receiver class code this way

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        Toast.makeText(context, “wow!! received new push notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Add GCM Service Class

As we have already declared “GcmBroadcastReceiver.java” in our Manifest file, So lets create this class
update receiver class code this way

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService
{     public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;     private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;     private final static String TAG = "GcmIntentService";     public GcmIntentService() {
     super("GcmIntentService");     
     }     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          Log.d(TAG, "Notification Data Json :" + extras.getString("message"));

          GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
          String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);          if (!extras.isEmpty()) {          if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
               .equals(messageType)) {
               sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
          } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
          .equals(messageType)) {
          sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
          + extras.toString());          // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
          } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
          .equals(messageType)) {
          // This loop represents the service doing some work.
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               Log.d(TAG," Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
               + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());               try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               }
             }
             Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
             sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
           }
        }        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
     }     // Put the message into a notification and post it.
     // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
     // a GCM message.
     private void sendNotification(String msg) {          mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
          .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,          new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class), 0);

          NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(          this)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
          .setContentTitle("Ocutag Snap")
          .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
          .setContentText(msg)
          .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

          mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);          mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to your specific problem, however, I was experiencing the same issue.  Everything was setup correctly, as far as I could tell, but the `onRegistered()` handler was never called.

I had the standard `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onDestroy()` service methods as part of my GCMIntentService class.  Once I removed them, the handler was called, as expected.

My assumption is that by overriding these methods, I was by-passing needed code initialization.

Comment: I don't have those function defined in mine but that's good to know. I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

After reading ClouDeveloper's post I removed `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, and the other *onXXX()* callback methods.  Also, my `GCMIntentService.onRegistered(Context, regId)` is called with the `regId`.

Thank you ClouDeveloper!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register with your application server in the [GCMBaseIntentService.onRegistered()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onRegistered%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) callback. Otherwise you will not be able to send your app messages.

You should really checkout [Google's GCM demo client](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git/samples/gcm-demo-client) as it provides a working sample with all of the correct code. We also have a working sample up on github: [airbop-client](https://github.com/indigorose/airbop-client). It   provides a slightly more complete example given that it has working interactions with an application server, which is necessary for a GCM enabled app. It works with the [AirBop](http://www.airbop.com) servers (which I helped create) which are free up to 1000 devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting response from the registration, one of the main reason is your manifest file is not configured correctly - especially give the "package_name" (your app package name like com.xxx.yyy) in the `<permission>` and `<intent filter>` correctly.