# How to call the C2DM PHP Function from the Android APP

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I am trying to add a Push Notification service to my Android Application.
I added the necessary methods in the application (Receiver, Manifest Changes etc.)

I then proceeded to follow this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121508/c2dm-implementation-php-code) to add the functions to my third party server for registration to C2DM and sending messages.

This may sound silly but as I am not that proficient at PHP can somebody please advise me on how to call the PHP functions to register/send messages from the Android App.

Thank you in advance, I will appreciate any help I receive.

RF

Comment: For the record, the PHP part of C2DM/GCM is not, technically speaking, **in** the Android app. It's somewhere on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, C2DM is dead. Long live [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)!

Secondly, [here's](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1273) an example.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into it

Comment: Always glad to help. That example was bookmarked, because it helped me get from idea to proof of concept in a little more than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 323go.

GCM is awesome. Really Easy to implement and use. For anyone that needs help with setting it up this is what I used:

[Android GCM Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438464/android-gcm-basic-implementation)

[PHP Server Code](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1273/)

Goodluck