# send error during onReceive in android GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying to send notifications via gcm to my android device. The registration was successful and i have the reg id saved on my server. When i send a test notification and keep my phone for debugging, the onReceive method is triggered in the demo app which means that the notification arrived. But, the intent also has the bundle -  Error:SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, message_type = send_error, google.message_id = 1

Could anyone tell me what might be the problem here?

Thanks,

Nitin

Edit: As it turned out, there was a problem with the firewall which was blocking the port at my office. Works fine at home.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To know that your device has been registering, I supose you might be checking it in [onRegistered](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onRegistered%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) function. Similarly, I think for receiving a message on your device you need to override ans use the [onMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onMessage%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) function in a class that extends `GCMBaseIntentService`. Something like:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent message) {
    Log.d("GCMIntentService","Received push message");
    Bundle extras=message.getExtras();
    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", "Received key: " +key +" and value as: "+extras.getString(key));
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do i need to add that as a receiver in my android manifest file ?

Comment: You need to mention a receiver in the manifest for which you would want to set up a service, which reacts to the received broadcast.

Comment: Which tutorial were you following? Read the official docs and try this question for basic implementation; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438464/android-gcm-basic-implementation

Comment: Looks like the GCMBaseIntentService is deprecated.

Comment: Yes it has been depreciated very recently. If you read the [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) guide, there is complete startup code for how to do it in new way.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i have looked into it.